# log4j:WARN No such property [append] in org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

Tags: java, spring, apache, logging, log4j

Can someone help me with this error message. I don't know why my application is not able to log messages. It is always showing the warning message when I run it. I could not get any much help in Google.

> log4j:WARN No such property [append] in
>   org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

I kept the `log4j.properties` file under src folder

```
log4j.debug=true  
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, STDOUT
log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %-32c{1} - %m\n
```

My application is a Spring MVC project

Here is the complete properties file

```
log4j.debug=true
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, STDOUT

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

#Redirect to Tomcat logs folder
#log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/logging.log

log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logigng.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %-32c{1} - %m\n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
#log4j.appender.STDOUT.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %-32c{1} - %m\n
```

Comment: paste your whole log4j.properties

Comment: If you have a Maven structure you should move your `log4j.properties` to `/src/main/resources` (and also to `/src/test/resources` in case you want to override those values when you run your tests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it.
Some dependency jar is causing this issue. Application is picking log4j.properties from that jar instead of what I provided. Anyhow that jar file is not required so I removed it.
I identified this by running JVM parameter

> -Dlog4j.debug

I still wonder is there any other way around it without removing this jar

Comment: Yes. the other way is to point the LogManager to your config file using , -Dlog4j.configurationFile= "your file location".